# Perl replace string in file using wildcard

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and trying to replace a line in a text file using a wildcard. Example file:

```
This is a text file.
```

My working (non-wildcard) example:

```
file=/home/test.user/test.txt
perl -pi -e 's/This is a text file./'"This is a modified text file."'/g' $file
```

Now trying to edit with a wildcard:

```
perl -pi -e 's/This*/'"This is a modified text file."'/g' $file
```

This is incorrect, and outputs:

```
This is a modified text file. is a text file.
```

How can I use a wildcard search with `/This*/`?

Comment: I recommend [*reading the documentation*](https://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html) for a language rather than guessing at its syntax, especially before asking the world for help. Perl uses *regular expressions* after the fashion of awk and sed. There is no reason to assume that a shell glob syntax is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl's `s///` uses a *regular expression pattern* to match the target, not a shell glob string.

Instead of `*`, try `.*` like this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/This.*/'"This is a modified text file."'/g' $file
```

`.*` matches zero or occurrences of any character except linefeed `LF` or `"\n"`.

Be careful, because it will match the substring *anywhere* in the string. So this string:

```
If This is a text file
```

will become this string:

```
If This is a modified text file
```

Therefore if you want to match beginning of line, then use an *anchor* `^` which insists that the rest of the pattern must match at the start of the string

```
perl -pi -e 's/^This.*/'"This is a modified text file."'/g' $file
```